# Conectar mi proyecto JavaSpringBoot con mi BD

Tags: java, base-de-datos, spring-boot

Hola me preguntaba porque me sale en gris esta configuración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Arriba a la derecha tenés un triangulo amarillo con signo de exclamación y al costado el número 5. Son 5 líneas que están en gris. Probablemente si haces click sobre ese ícono te muestre más datos

Comment: Te lo pone en gris poque cursojava no es una palabra valida en ningún diccionario